# Regarding the "usual hypothesis" of a filtration.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In different literature I have seen often they refer to the "usual hypothesis" of a filtration, but I see two different varieties.

In both cases we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, and a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$. In both cases they assume that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all sets of probability 0, and they assume that the filtration is right continuous.

But some also assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is completed aswell. As I see in this case that means that for every t, all $\mathcal{F}_t$ is complete aswell? I can see why we would like this, because then when  we work with almost sure events we do not get any problems.

But what about the first case, where they assume "usual" hypothesis but don't explicitly say that $\mathcal{F}$ is complete? Am I to assume in these cases that there is an error? Or can there be spaces, where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ is not complete, but the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ contains all the zero-sets for every t, but may not be complete? If this is really meant in some literature, is there an easy explanation as to why this may be beneficial, what is the benefit of having all the 0-probability sets, but we may not have subsets of 0-sets measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's assumed that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is complete. Remember that $\mathcal{F}_0\subset\mathcal{F}_s\subset\mathcal{F}_t\subset\mathcal{F}$, for all $0\leq s < t< \infty$, therefore, if $\mathcal{F}_0$ is complete (in the sense it contains all the null sets with respect to $\mathcal{F}$), then all $\mathcal{F}_t$ is complete.

Because of this, if the filtration satisfy the "usual hypothesis" or "usual conditions", then $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_t, P)$ is complete for all $t\geq 0$.